# Interface с одним ключём одного типа и множеством динамических ключей другого типа - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, интерфейс, типы, react-hook

Существует 2 готовых типа:

```
type ContainerData = string;
type ContainerDataArray = string[];
```

Необходимо написать интерфейс, который имеет одно обязательное поле `rootContainer` типа `ContainerDataArray` и **неограниченное** количество полей с **любым** названием типа `ContainerData`. Использование выглядит так:

```
interface IContainerBundle {
    // Обязательное поле
    rootContainer: ContainerDataArray,

    // Другие поля с любым названием.
    // Есть ли способ реализовать такой функционал?
    // (что-то): ContainerData
}

const containerBundle: IContainerBundle = {
    rootContainer: ["", ""],
    container1: "",
    container2: "",
    // ...
}
```

Жёсткая привязка к первым двум типам обязательна: так как приложение всё ещё находится на этапе разработки, содержимое типов может изменяться.

Решение вида:

```
interface IContainerBundle {
    [key: string]: ContainerData | ContainerDataArray
}
```

не является правильным, так как обязательное поле `rootContainer` **всегда** должно быть массивом строк, а остальные поля **всегда** обычными строками.

Данный функционал используется при инициализации `useState` в `React`. Получается что-то типа:

```
interface IContainerBundle {
    // ...
}
const [container, setContainer] = useState<IContainerBundle>({
    rootContainer: ["...", "..."],
    container1: "",
    container2: ""
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigbygDwFxQB2ArgLYBGECANFCASgnIQOZQC+AsAFCiRQBlCAGMA9oQAm6LFDgSCJClVr0iZSgg48efaANLAAFtMw8o5qAlGjgBeMmA92UAGRYzFgNoBrCCFmEUIzMLAC6BEJikk7a3BIiADYAhgjQAG4puBEGhrE4AHRWNvlyUAD0ZVAAClaQCKBQAORyjVASohBIRDZQEDhwKFDiULpN9iiN+TwFRcD5ONIADNOF1nP+GABEAF67m3n5NoZUJVIYAIwrRycLFdW1VA2NOK3tnd2ofQOow6ONkeIJJMrkYThsoAAmHhAA)

```
type First = { x: number, y: string }
type Second = { id: number, y: number }

type Smth = {
    root: First
} & {
    [key in string]: Second
}

declare var x: Smth

x.root.id // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'First'.
x.root.x = 0
x.root.y = "zzz"

x.other.id = 1
x.other.x // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Second'.
x.other.y = 2
```

Немного манипуляций с кастомными хуками: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggThAygQwLYQDwBUA0UCqeAmngHIB8UAvFABQYAa5tAlNZQ1BAB7AQB2AEwDOULFAD8UAIxQAXFABMbHnyGj6TVuyidVAkQUkz5StlKKnSAbgCwAKAehIUAGIBLOMODUoAbyhuBX4AV1QAIwg4PBAFbzh3fgBzKABfJ3BoRAgAYwB7IV8A90FgsMjoqFioUIiotIcMl0RUYAALDABpLl4DUXjEpMoaPwcocag4PLzgBQ8vYAdUqAAyfzGJgG0AawgQKESoToBdBXgkNExdkDwAIimZ27x57zxs-KFyJcb7ADMQ-g5YDuApQELCJCtDrdfTqKADZLMIJQFrtLrkNijewTKAAelxgQAdA9gISSniCQAFKaQOCgKAAchKDKggjyEFE-BmPXc3igoOc0AZL2ADMJG3G3GJ01J3F8AAYJUSSYT9jRbgAvLW3H44-FQal5Wn0hkzNpRFlsjk1bk8Xk+AWZRmo6HkMVK-VSs1RMmCXzSD0Er3tH3cQNE71wVW+RTfRz2cGQ9q0LE4kkKALI+UxBS3W5pHBLFg-RMulNK9P+QIKbNVXP51KF7ETSMZg6lGQ5pQFos-f6A4Gg0tQxRdHpqQwIoa0ZEu9EsBQANzyJTsfwBQJB-DBEJdo5hvThU6RCjnx8x4alKvJ+sNxv2TMElvZnNt3Ht-O3gsZIvdzcl0ozISco0Iq-7KjK0bqlqGo6vGOLBuaUbkjQAbgZ6hKRsBFIGjSUQmtwz7WlyPh2nyjouAy7wFE+4rgYhPpqkocYOMO7SKOW4GVpmNZdnmPb2KkxbxmxbQcamEzcdWUC1tU-GNkqrZViUCjSF2igCUJQA)

```
type AreSame<T, U, Y, N> = (<X>() => X extends T ? 1 : 2) extends (<X>() => X extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;

type First = { x: number, y: string }
type Second = { id: number, y: number }

type Smth<K extends string> = {
    root: First
} & {
    [key in K]: AreSame<key, "root", First, Second>
}

function useSmth<K extends string>(x: Smth<K>) {
    // x.root.id // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'First'.
    x.root.x = 0
    x.root.y = "zzz"

    // Property 'other' does not exist on type 'Smth<K>'.
    // x.other.id = 1
    // x.other.x
    // x.other.y = 2
}

useSmth({
    root: { x: 0, y: "" },
})

useSmth({
    root: { x: 0, y: "" },
    other: { id: 1, y: 2 },
})

function useSmth2<K extends string>(x: Smth<K>): void;
function useSmth2<K extends string>(x: Smth<string>) {
    // x.root.id // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'First'.
    x.root.x = 0
    x.root.y = "zzz"

    x.other.id = 1
    // x.other.x // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Second'.
    x.other.y = 2
}

useSmth2({
    root: { x: 0, y: "" },
})

useSmth2({
    root: { x: 0, y: "" },
    other: { id: 1, y: 2 },
})
```

Comment: Есть способ сделать так же, но с инициализацией переменной через ```const```?

Comment: @Vladislav, при чём тут вообще переменная, ты же тип просил - вот он.

Comment: @Vladislav, а понял. Блин.. Неожиданно. Сейчас подумаю.

Comment: Тут просто проблема в том, что этот тип используется при инициализации ```useState``` в ```React```. ```const [containers, setContainers] = useState<IContainerBundle>({...})```. Поэтому через declare тут не получится сделать :/ Наверное, стоило указать это в вопросе. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @Vladislav, пока ничего лучше каста объекта к нужному типу не придумал. А ты собираешься объект прям в useState запихивать, без функции? Не `useState((): IContainerBundle => ({ ... }))`?

Comment: Он что так, что так не работает. Поначалу с функцией делал, потом начал просто объект запихивать.

Comment: @Vladislav, с функцией можно нахимичить тип функции. Хотя, там мутно получается. А ты не собираешься использовать кастомный хук, в который этот объект будет передаваться?

Comment: С кастомным хуком получается то же самое, только ошибки в другом месте выдаются, но в целом всё то же самое.

Comment: @Vladislav, нет, для кастомного хука я бы по-другому написал сингатуру generic'а.

Comment: Если не трудно, можно пример? Я, честно говоря, не сильно понимаю, как по-другому реализовать такой хук.

Comment: @Vladislav, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Всё, вроде получилось. Спасибо, дружище!)